# Navigation property returns null after inserting

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've migrated my application from EF4 to EF5.
I used the below code with the previous version to get related entity of a newly added item.

```
Student s = new Student();
s.Name = _name;
s.ClassID = _cID;

db.Students.Add(s);
db.SaveChanges();

ClassRoom c = s.ClassRoom;
```

so I used to get the specific class entity to `c`. But now `s.ClassRoom` returns null.

How do I get the `ClassRoom` entity for the student? Do I have to use `db.ClassRooms.FirstOrDefault(....)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that you have not loaded the navigation property yet.

You can use:

```
db.Students.Include("ClassRoom")
```

or

```
using System.Data.Entity;
db.Students.Include(s=>s.ClassRoom)
```

to eagerly load the nav property

the other option is to enable lazy loading by marking the navigation property with virtual. I personally prefer the former (eager loading) as it encourages more performant code.

Also check out my navigation properties article here, I talk about loading near the start http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first

Your code should read as follows:

```
Student s = new Student();
s.Name = _name;
s.ClassID = _cID;

db.Students.Add(s);
db.SaveChanges();

//reload the entity from the DB with its associated nav property
s = db.Students.Include(s=>s.ClassRoom).Single(st=>st.StudentId == s.StudentId);
ClassRoom c = s.ClassRoom;
```

Comment: Is it introduced with EF5?

Comment: @LibinTK It is there from the beginning of EF, I think.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Yeah.. I've seen it before. But it was working even without `db.Students.Include("ClassRooms")`

Comment: @LibinTK with code first lazy loading is disabled when you dont have virtual properties. I believe its enabled by default if you generate your context from the modelbuilder. With lazy loading enabled you wont see this issue.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor How do I use it in my context? `var e = db.Students.Include("ClassRoom").FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ClassID==s.ClassID)`?

Comment: @LibinTK see edits, you will need to get the student again (like you commented)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Thank you so much for the edits. But if I need only the `ClassRoom` entity then `var e = db.ClassRooms.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.ID==s.ClassID)` would be enough... right?

Comment: @LibinTK yeah absolutally, you could also assign this entity to the nav property and save it as an alternative to setting `s.ClassID = _cID;`