# Entity Framework navigation property not set when adding entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

When I add an a new entity to a table I would want to populate the navigation properties after saving the changes. How would I do this?

Here's what I'm doing now, and the navigation property Condition is null. I have checked that the foreign key has been set. I also tried just assigning to the nav property manually by reading from the other table directly but even that did not work.

```
...
var group = _context.Groups.AddRange(groups).First();
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
// group.Condition which is a navigation property is null after this. 
// The property does work when I get the group from the context, after adding.
```

Comment: Have you tried `var group = _context.Groups.AddRange(groups).First().Include(x=>x.Condition);`

Comment: That doesn't work, can't even use Include there. Doing an update of the entity where I use Include after saving did it.

Answer (score 4):

This will be the case when lazy loading is disabled. Enable it by adding `virtual` keyword to the properties. You can also use eager loading by using `_context.Groups.Include("Condition")`

You can get details from similar question [Navigation property returns null after inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629843/navigation-property-returns-null-after-inserting)

Comment: The property was already marked virtual. I got it to work by looking at your link though. Include did it, however I had to update the entity after saving.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work by checking [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629843/navigation-property-returns-null-after-inserting) provided by Ankit Sinha:

```
var group = _context.Groups.AddRange(groups).First();
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
var group = _context.Groups.Include(x => x.Condition).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == group.id);
```