# Navigation property is NULL after insert in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, insert, navigation-properties

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629843/navigation-property-returns-null-after-inserting) that suggests an answer but my situation is a bit different.

```
// Create a new Lunch entity with these two properties.
Lunch lunchEntity = new LunchEntity();
lunchEntity.UserId = userId;
lunchEntity.MealId = mealId;

// Add the entity to the DbContext and save the changes.
restaurantEntities.Lunches.Add(lunchEntity);
restaurantEntities.SaveChanges();

// Get the Lunch entity that we inserted above.
Lunch mySavedLunchEntity = restaurantEntities.Lunches.Find(lunchEntity.Id);
```

Now, after inserting the Lunch entity, I need to have its instance with all of its navigation properties included. That's why I use the Find() method to select the newly created entity. The problem is that the User navigation property is null, while the Meal navigation property has a reference to the correct object.

Moreover, if I execute this statement

```
Lunch mySavedLunchEntity = restaurantEntities.Lunches.Find(lunchId);
```

separately in another method that is supposed to retrieve a Lunch entity for a particular Id, all navigation properties are included correctly.

So, my question is why all my navigation properties are included when I just query a given element, and some of them are not, if I query the element only after it has been inserted?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Lunch mySavedLunchEntity = restaurantEntities.Lunches.Where(l => l.LunchId == lunchId).Include(l => l.User).Include(l => l.Meal)
```

This forces EF to load the two navigation properties instead of Lazy loading them.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I know this solves the problem but I don't want to do this because it works normally without them when I just query an entity. I just can't figure out why it works differently when I query after an insert operation.